# How to configure `Content-Length' header in HTTP protocol

Tags: http, content-length, http-content-length

I don't clear about how to count `Content-Length' header in HTTP.

Take an example,

```
HEADER
...
Content-Type: text/html
(blank line `\r\n')
<html></html>
(blank line `\r\n')
```

This is a working http request sending an empty HTML page(correct me if any problem :-)). Then what should be the length of content? 15 or 17(take the blank line between header and sending entity into account)?

Thanks in advance. Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [W3 Content-Lentgth](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) is defined as followed:

> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the
>   entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in
>   the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would
>   have been sent had the request been a GET.

As far as I understand it, you have to count everything after the first line break. My answer to your question would be **`15`** then.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Since I'm now receiving data from a `keep-alive` connection, so I think I'd better extract the `Content-Length` field as a counter and reading specified bytes of data starting from entity. Unfortunately, when the stream ends, the counter is 2 instead of 0. I can't figure it out, and I think the additive 2 is for the blank line between header and entity, but I can't find any documents rectify my assumption.

Comment: You should definately NOT be hard-coding an offset. Read the headers, skip the blank line and line break foLlowing the headers, then read however many bytes the `Content-Length` header says to read. Also keep in mind that some responses may use a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header instead of a `Content-Length` header, so be prepared for that, as well as responses that use a disconnect instead of either header at all. Read RFC 2616, it explains how to handle an entity length correctly.

Answer (score 2):

15 is the correct answer. That counts the line break at the *END* of the entity data, which means that line break is part of the entity, not the http protocol. *DO NOT* count the line break between the headers and entity.

Comment: Good explanation! The first line break is part of the HTTP specification, therefor do not count it.

Comment: Sorry, *\r\n* (the one at the end of the entity body) counts 2 bytes, right? If I analyse the request body with software like wireshark, \r\n counts two bytes, 0d 0a in HEX value, but if I export those bytes into a file I see a ^M insted of the \r\n character, and it counts 1 byte only, so how should I handle this?

Comment: Yes, `\r\n` is 2 bytes, `0d 0a`. `^M` is just how some text editors display `0d` when it is by itself without a trailing `0a`. If you see 2 bytes in the capture, but only 1 byte is being exported, then the export is faulty. That has nothing to do with the HTTP protocol itself